# Why not use singletons with no instances and only static methods in C++?

Tags: c++, static, singleton

What is the point in writing a singleton with an instance getter when you could just use static methods and not need to do that?

Here is a simplified version of an event handler singleton I am writing with only static methods:

```
class EventHandler {
private:
   static std::vector<std::function<void()>> m_events; //implemented in cpp
public:
    EventHandler() = delete;
    static void addEvent(std::function<void()> evt) { m_events.push_back(evt); }
};
```

To me it seems way more simple and intuitive only to have static methods since `EventHandler`'s purpose is to restrict visiblity to methods and variables that would normally be global. What would be the advantage of writing a private constructor, non-static methods and variables, and a public instance getter?

Comment: Often the point is you might want to have more than one later, or it's derived from some base class which has more than one derived class

Comment: A singleton has the same advantages and disadvantages as statics, since a singleton is really a static in disguise. Both are very much overused and often misused, which makes comparing trade-offs more difficult.  Singletons are often packaged (or encapsulated) better than statics, so are *easier* to manage (e.g. defer construction to first use, rather than construct on definition and "reinitialise" later [and forget to reinitialise!]) particularly in larger programs. Things like reuse - which beginners rarely care about - are (somewhat) easier with a singleton than a static.

Comment: You'll also struggle to avoid static initialisation order issues which can be worked around when using a singleton

Comment: What the point is depends on the situation, and there might not be one. For this particularly simple case, some free functions might be better.

Comment: If you don't need a class instance at all, a namespace with free functions might be a more sensible option.

Comment: The free functions should be fine for you. But in general you will NOT need globals/statics at all if you use dependency injection. Create an instance of EventHandler in main and just pass it on by (const) reference to the code that needs access to share state. Even better inject an interface/abstract baseclass to your code, this will make your code unit testable.

Answer (score 0):

One possible advantages of singleton over *"static class"* is the possibility to use `const`. Improving expressiveness.